# javascript change color of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code but it just wont work. what could the problem be? Is my syntax wrong or is the whole method wrong?

```
<input checked="checked" class="form-field" id="IsCurrentlySmokingrightNej" name="IsCurrentlySmokingright" type="radio" value="Nej">
<input class="form-field" id="IsCurrentlySmokingrightJa" name="IsCurrentlySmokingright" type="radio" value="Ja">
    <input id="IsCurrentlySmokingrighttextbox" name="IsCurrentlySmokingright" type="text" style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0); float: right; width: 50px;">
```

javascript:

```
 $(document).on("change", "IsCurrentlySmokingrightNej", function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("IsCurrentlySmokingrightNej");
    var ele = $("#IsCurrentlySmokingrighttextbox");
    if (elem.checked) {
        ele.css("background-color", "rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)");
        ele.css("float", "right");
        ele.css("width", "50px");

    }
});

   $(document).on("change", "IsCurrentlySmokingrightJa", function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("IsCurrentlySmokingrightJa");
        var ele = $("#IsCurrentlySmokingrighttextbox");
        if(elem.checked){
            ele.css("background-color", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1");//röd
            ele.css("float", "right");
            ele.css("width", "50px");
        }

});
```

Comment: Add a `#` before `IsCurrentlySmokingrightJa`, so `$(document).on("change", "#IsCurrentlySmokingrightJa"...`

Answer (score 3):

you missed `#` in front of id selector

```
 $(document).on("change", "#IsCurrentlySmokingrightNej", function() {
                      //---^---here
```

same goes for the rest..

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the # or . if it is id then # and if class name then .

```
$(document).on("change", "#IsCurrentlySmokingrightNej", function() {
                          ^^^ # here as it is id
```

And one more thing:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("IsCurrentlySmokingrightNej");
```

Why are you using this line even though you are not using it anywhere.

Comment: I acctually used that code before but i have modified the code a couple of times so now it was only in the way of the code. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielGustafsson ok, just to know to understand the question properly. well no prob.